# how to create a debian package using “equivs-build” which can be “upgraded” if already installed?

Tags: package, debian, upgrade, dpkg, package-management

I have created a `.deb` package using `equivs-build` command and providing necessary `control`, `preinst`, `postinst`, etc. I noticed that `version` can also be mentioned in control file. Now I want to create a `.deb` package with updated source code and I want to enable user to upgrade the package if it is already installed (and is of previous version, of course), as I won't be changing `conf` related files, etc. One way I can think of is to write a shell-script which will first check for installed version, and will take actions accordingly (i.e. if installed, just update the source-code, database-migrations, etc. and if not, install the package using `dpkg -i <package-name>`). I was wondering if there was a way to achieve using `dpkg` only (something like `dpkg upgrade <package-name>`) which will handle installation or up-gradation as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's already how it works.

`dpkg -i package_0.123.deb` will upgrade if the version of package is less than 0.123, removing the previous version if necessary (there's an option to force a downgrade, too). `apt-get install package` will install the newest version of package, removing the old one and upgrading to a new one if necessary. `apt-get upgrade` will upgrade all packages to the newest version.

Basically, just take care to monotonically upgrade the version number each time you publish a new build.

If you didn't specify a version previously, the default will be something simple like 1.0. Just make it bigger than that.

Comment: Yes. Just figured out the changes I will need to do in `prerm`, `postrm` and `preinst` scripts. https://wiki.debian.org/MaintainerScripts is the detailed explanation and flow for upgrading a package using `dpkg`. Thanks for the help.